# Runtime-Error on productive Server but not locally

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-errors

so i finished one of my ASP.NET-projects and want to deploy it on the productive server. And suddenly WHOOM: Runtime error!

Okay, no problem; look at the error message, see the stack trace, solve problem, everybody happy. Peanuts!

The server tells me, that the `customErrors`-Settings in my `web.config` are set that no error messages are displayed. So I take a look at the file and what do I see? `<customErrors mode="Off" />`.

I tried to change hat to `On`, `RemoteOnly` and whatever else. Nothing changed. How come the server doesn't recognize the setting correctly, as when I Debug the pages in VS'08 everything works perfectly fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the IIS application is using the correct version of ASP.NET - sometimes it will default to 1.1.

In IIS6, right-click on the website or virtual directory and go to properties > ASP.NET tab. It will have a drop-down to select which version of .NET to use.

For IIS7, follow the [instructions here](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx).

Comment: Thought of that too, but as I'm completely new to MS-Servers, where can I edit that certain applications use 1.1 and other can use 2.0 or even 3.5 of .NET?